# ERROR: InvalidProfileError - The config profile (default) could not be found despite having config file in place

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to SSH to my EB instance but

```
eb ssh 
eb ssh --setup
```

Both gives me

```
ERROR: InvalidProfileError - The config profile (default) could not be found
```

I did check $HOME/.aws/config which was generate through eb-cli and it does seem to be in the right place with correctly generated credential.

```
[profile eb-cli]
aws_access_key_id = correctkeyid
aws_secret_access_key = correctaccesskey
```

I copied config file and threw it in [project]/.aws just to see if it does anything but still the same error as expected.

Comment: At the very least, consult https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/welcome.html
Let me know if more specific support should be provided.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `eb ssh` cli tool is attempting to read back AWS profile entries for a `default` AWS profile (typically from `~/.aws/config` and `~/.aws/credentials` files), but the profile contained in these files is a *named* profile – named as `eb-cli`, from the line `[profile eb-cli]`.

Option 1) In the project, edit the `.elasticbeanstalk/config.yml` file

- from `profile: default`
- to `profile: eb-cli`

Option 2) Edit the bracketed names in the those `~/.aws/*` files to align with the profile name declared in the `config.yml` file.

Or update all of these entries to something more meaningful to the project, such as `my-project`. Once these profile names align, you'll be able to connect with `eb ssh`.

---

**Note** that the `~/.aws/*` configuration files support multiple named profile entries, which enables having multiple projects linked to differently named AWS profiles.